# Data concatenation as steganography technique

Tags: c#, steganography

For example, I recorded a video using my camera and saved it as `my_vacation.mp4` which size is 50MB. I opened the video file and an encrypted file called `secret_message.dat` using Visual Studio, by using `File.ReadAllBytes()` in C#, concatenated both arrays of bytes, and then saved it as `my_vacation_2.mp4`.

The program I created for testing purpose is able to save the byte index where the hidden file begin and I want to use it as key to extract that hidden file later.

Now I can play that video file normally, without any error. Total file size is 65MB. Suppose no one could access the original file, of course no one would know that the last 15MB part of that video file is actually another file, right?

What might be the flaw of this technique? Is this also a valid steganography technique?

Comment: no one would know that the last 15MB part of that video file is actually another file, right? mp4 decoder will know it. Maybe they would not know what the data means, but they will know that something is appended into file.

Comment: Steganography tries to hide the message while making it impossible to determine whether a message is there or not - that certainly doesn't apply in your case, since the container has enough information about the content that it's trivial to find your message (hint: look at content length headers, and you'll see all those 15 MiBs in plain sight). You just obfuscated things a bit, but if I put two different videos, one with a message and another without, you could easily see which one has the message. A proper approach would encode the message in the video data itself, for example.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan but then someone has to open the video file to see what is inside the file (audio & video track, metadata, and finally the hidden file) for a reason

Comment: Yes, and that reason is simply that they don't trust you. That's what security analysts do. Each technique should be examined within a context; your method may work on an unsuspected friend but you absolutely can't talk your way out of it once an expert (not even that) looks at the file. And that's a flaw in the context of how likely it's to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid steganography technique?

Yes, it is. The definition of steganography is hiding information in another medium without someone suspecting its presence or existence. Just because it may be a bad approach doesn't change its intentions at all. If anything, a multitude of papers on steganography mention this technique in their introduction section as an example of how steganography can be applied.

> What might be the flaw of this technique?

There are mainly 2 flaws: it is trivial to detect and is absolutely fragile to modification attacks.

Many formats encode their data either by a header which says in advance how many bytes to read before the end of file, or by putting an end-of-file marker, which means to keep on reading data until the marker is encountered. By attaching your data after that, you ensure they won't be read by the appropriate format decoder. This can fool your 11-year old cousin who knows nothing about that sort of stuff, but anyone mildly experienced can load the file and count how many bytes were read. If there are unaccounted bytes in the physical file, that will instantly raise red flags.

Even worse, it's trivial to fully extract your secret. You may argue it's encrypted, but remember, the aim of steganography is to not raise any suspicion. Most steganalysis approaches put a statistical number to it, e.g., 60% there is a message hidden in X medium. A few others can go a bit further and guess the approximate length of the embedded secret. In comparison, you're already caught red-handed.

Talking about length, a file of X bitrate/compression and Y duration approximately results to a file of size Z. Even an unsavvy one will know what's up when the size is 30% larger than expected.

Now, imagine your file is communicated through an insecure channel where a warden inspects its contents and if he suspects foul play, he can modify the file so that the recipient doesn't get the message. In this case, it's as simple as loading the file and resaving it. In fact, your method is so fragile it can be destroyed by even the most unintentional of attacks. By just uploading your track to a site for playback, it can unwittingly reencode it for higher compression, just because it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose no one could access the original file, of course no one would know that the last 15MB part of that video file is actually another file, right?

No. Your secret file is encrypted, so that probably rules out any headers showing up in hex editor, but there is a problem - MP4 container format and its structure is well known.
You can extract all video/audio tracks and what you are left with is some metadata and your secret message, so it will be obvious that it's not supposed to be there.

It is a valid technique, just not a very effective one.